# How to add objectclass and custom attribute to LDIF file?

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, ldif

I am using LDAP authentication in spring-security. For some reason I don't have an LDAP server and I have configured my `spring-security.xml` to use the LDIF file.

I need to add a custom attribute, called `type` for the users. So I created an `objectclass` and an `attributetypes` as mentioned [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/idmanage.1012/b15883/ldif_appendix003.htm).

The LDIF file looks like :

```
dn: cn=subschemasubentry 
changetype: modify 
add: attributetypes 
attributetypes: ( 1.2.3.4.5.6.7 NAME 'type' DESC 'New attribute definition'  
 EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch SYNTAX '1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15' ) 

dn: cn=subschemasubentry
changetype: modify
add: objectClasses
objectClasses: ( 1.2.3.4.56789.1.0.200 NAME 'testUser' 
 SUP ( inetOrgPerson ) STRUCTURAL
 MUST cn 
 MAY type )

dn: ou=users,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

dn: uid=testuser1,ou=users,dc=springframework,dc=org
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: testUser
mail: test1@test.com
cn: Some Name
sn: someName
uid: someId
type: someType
userPassword: pass1
```

However, this fails with `NameNotFoundException`, when I try to use some REST call (protected by `spring-security`) with the error :

```
LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT: 
...
...
Attempt to search under non-existant entry: ou=users,dc=springframework,dc=org];
nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
```

If I remove the custom attribute and the custom objectclass, and change the user data to `objectclass: inetOrgPerson`, it works fine.

How can I add the `objectclass` and the attributes then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to use the schema in LDIF files, which was wrong. I used ApacheDS to create new schema with the custom attributes and custom objectclass. Then exported them to LDIF.

The resulting LDIF I added to the LDIF file used for spring-security.

It is another matter that spring still does not read the new attributes from entries even when it reads the object classes.

Comment: Do you finally found a solution ?